# What does "on lead" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

Could somebody please tell me what does "to be on lead" mean? (As in "the law firm requested to be on lead").

Comment: Is it a law firm?

Comment: Can you give us any more information about the circumstances in which the request was made? For example, were there several participants in something?

Comment: The request was mentioned in a record of a meeting between a law firm and two certain committees.

Comment: The **lead counsel** (in the US) acts as a sort of project manager and head honcho. The lead counsel parcel out assignments to the other law firms acting on behalf of the client, in various local jurisdictions for example. All information flows through the lead firm and they often make the final decision on how a particular issue is to be addressed.

Comment: There is another example in [here](http://www.europarl.europa.eu/sides/getDoc.do?type=COMPARL&reference=PE-585.484&format=PDF&language=EN&secondRef=01). **"ECON has requested to be on lead or to work on the basis of Rule 55."**

Answer (score 1):

If someone is *on lead* or *taking the lead* it often means that they are coordinating a group of people on the same project or towards a similar goal.

For example, I used to have a job at the telephone help desk for my university, and one of the call desk agents would "lead agent" if they were the one coordinating things like breaks, or monitoring the general flow of calls coming into the center.